# Unable to get angular-fullpage.js to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, fullpage.js

This is my first AngularJS project, and I am trying to get the [angular-fullpage.js](https://github.com/hellsan631/angular-fullpage.js) directive to work.

I think I have set it up correctly, and I was confused by the fact that the current version of AngularJS will not work with angular-fullpage.js. I I resolved it to work with AngularJS 1.4.4 which resolved to 1.4.12, but nothing happens on the page where angular-fullpage is supposed to be loaded.

Maybe I have missed something.

When installing via `bower`:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
    1) angular#~1.4.4 which resolved to 1.4.12 and is required by angular-fullpage.js#0.2.1
    2) angular#1.5.8 which resolved to 1.5.8 and is required by angular-route#1.5.8
    3) angular#^1.5.8 which resolved to 1.5.8

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer !1
bower angular                          resolution Saved angular#~1.4.4 as resolution
bower angular-fullpage.js#^0.2.1          install angular-fullpage.js#0.2.1
bower angular#~1.4.4                      install angular#1.4.12
bower fullpage.js#~2.7.7                  install fullpage.js#2.7.9

angular-fullpage.js#0.2.1 bower_components\angular-fullpage.js
+-- angular#1.4.12
+-- fullpage.js#2.7.9

angular#1.4.12 bower_components\angular

fullpage.js#2.7.9 bower_components\fullpage.js
+-- jquery#3.1.0
```

#### bower.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.8",
    "gsap": "^1.19.0",
    "fastclick": "^1.0.6",
    "normalize-css": "^4.2.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "angular-fullpage.js": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.4.4"
  }
```

#### app.module.js

```
var mrThunder = angular.module('MrThunder', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
```

#### app.module-fullpage.js

```
;(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('mrThunder', [
      'fullPage.js'
    ]);

})();
```

#### HTML

```
<div full-page>
        <section class="section hero-container">
            <h1>work</h1>
        </section>

        <section class="section work-examples-container" ng-repeat="workExample in workExamples">
            <h2>work examples</h2>
        </section>
</div>
```

Scripts are loaded:

```
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-fullpage.js/angular-fullpage.js"></script>

    <script src="bower_components/fullpage.js/vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/fullpage.js/vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/fullpage.js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.module-fullpage.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/maincontroller.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

The angular-fullpage.js depandancy is working as it adds an event      but jquery.fullPage.min.js is not adding events. I took a screengrab of my code to compare to the github example.
My code
[image]

Working [example](http://hellsan631.github.io/angular-fullpage.js)
[image]

Comment: include it before `jquery.easings.min.js`

Comment: cheers, I did that but no change :(

Comment: remove `.js` from here `bower_components/angular-fullpage.js`

Comment: it's only `bower_components\angular-fullpage.js`

Comment: remove the extra bower_components\angular-fullpage.js\angular-fullpage.js

Comment: you have to change the order also check my update to the answer

Comment: what do you mean by extra `bower_components\angular-fullpage.js\angular-fullpage.js`? I removed the .js `bower_components/angular-fullpage.js` but I got `Cannot GET /bower_components/angular-fullpage/angular-fullpage.js`. Thanks for your help

Comment: it's just the order that you have to change look at my updated answer

Comment: Now fullPage.js version 3 (no jQuery required) is available for Angular in the official repository: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/angular-fullpage